# URL.init?(string: String) returns 'nil' when it shouldn't

Tags: swift

I'm experiencing an issue with the Foundation struct URL's string initializer. I'll post some code from the repl below:

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7).
Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> let testString = "https://www.apple.com"
testString: String = "https://www.apple.com"
  3> let testUrl1 = URL(string: testString)
testUrl1: URL? = nil
  4> let testUrl2 = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
testUrl2: URL? = nil
```

I cannot think of why this is happening, if you look at the source for the initializer, located at https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/URL.swift#L495 you'll see this in the documentation:

```
/// Initialize with string.
///
/// Returns `nil` if a `URL` cannot be formed with the string (for example, if the string contains characters that are illegal in a URL, or is an empty string).
```

As far as I can tell though, the string I am testing with is a valid URL and the initializer shouldn't be returning nil. I have tried this on two different Macs and in a freshly installed virtual machine, and have gotten the same result in all of them. macOS 10.15, Xcode 11.1. Anyone have any insight into what might be wrong?

Comment: Seems to work in Playgrounds

Comment: I see the same behavior in REPL in 11.0, but if you `print(testUrl1)`, it actually is set.

Comment: Very bizarre, might just be an issue with the REPL I suppose. I’d be more comfortable to be sure about it though. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear to be a REPL issue and existed in 11.0, too. But if you `print(testUrl1)`, you’ll see it really is set.

Comment: When did this bug start? I just tested in Swift 4.0.3 and it works fine there.

Comment: Not sure. I can only confirm that I’ve seen it in Xcode 11.0 and 11.1...

Comment: It's a weird one; you want to report it to bugs.swift.org? I don't see anything parallel there.

Comment: Feel free, if you’d like. I probably wouldn’t get to it for a while...

Comment: I'm going to guess that the bug is related to this one: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11546 REPL is LLDB in some sense, and we LLDB is misreporting non-nil Optional Foundation overlay type instances as nil. So this could be another form of that.